# Parsing xlsx or csv at the UI level or through backendservice?

Tags: java, parsing

Which of these two options is better ,parsing an xlsx or csv at the UIlevel level or rather passing it to the backend service as a blob and then parsing it ?

Comment: blob? Storing in DB? Not good. A big csv processed by presentation layer? Not good. A csv/xls copied to a server's directory and processed by a backend service? I would take that one

Comment: But wouldn't that add a slight latency due to the original file getting copied to some location and then accessed by the service from that location... a blob could be serialized and de-serialized and would allow making the application generic

Comment: If the blob is only used temporarily, fine. If you store it in a DB, it will throw away any DB growth estimation AND for sure, the OS is better on file handling than a DBMS.